# Ubuntu 18.4 PCoIP agent (new to ubuntu, many years since I last used linux)

Tags: virtualization

I'm trying to build a Ubuntu 18.4 or 16.4 TLS virtual machine in esxi 6.7 vsphere environment with View Horizon 7.5. Unable to connect to vm with PCoIP is there anyone who has been able to connect to a vm with PCoIP.